# Failed to clone using git in hudson

Tags: git, hudson

This question has driving me mad,  i tried to integrated Git in hudson, but after installed the plugin (Jenkins GIT plugin V1.16) and create a job using Git as the SCM tool, everytime i tried to build this job,it will failed immediately ,attached the error stack trace info as following:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building remotely on William
Checkout:testgit / C:\Hudson\workspace\testgit - hudson.remoting.Channel@78b4c4:William
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:testgit / C:\Hudson\workspace\testgit - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@167d3c4
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from ssh:git@github.com:williamhu1985/robotium.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:852)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:812)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:1931)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can using the git bash to clone the repo, but not sure why it failed with hudson ,is there anyone who encounter this question before, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clone the repo as the same user on the same machine that the jenkins job is running?

Answer (score 1):

> Fetching upstream changes from ssh:git@github.com:williamhu1985/robotium.git

The URL is wrong, it should be either:

- ssh://git@github.com:williamhu1985/robotium.git

OR

- https://github.com/williamhu1985/robotium.git